# What does "transit" mean in the context of an MPLS network?

Tags: internet, mpls, network

We've had a quote submitted by an ISP to change our current numerous Internet connections over to a managed MPLS network however on the quote it is mentioned that it includes "X mb of transit in our data centre".

What exactly does that mean? I've searched online for "MPLS transit" etc. but can't seem to find an explanation of what it means?

Comment: Possibly the amount of traffic you have across the MPLS links? MB = Megabyte?

Comment: Mbit or Megabyte? Could either be the amount of megabytes you transmit or the amount of Mbit you utilize.

Comment: I'm guessing they're referring to internet transit.  IOW - raw internet.

Comment: "mb" taken literally is "millibit" with 1000 mb = 1 bit. Prepare for a hefty bill...

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We queried it and were told that it's the amount of external traffic permitted. Internal traffic isn't counted.

Answer (score 0):

Transit has nothing to do directly with MPLS. TRANSIT: the carrying of people, goods, or materials from one place to another. In your case bandwidth.

You do have a good question though because some of my customers have found the wording isn't as simple as upload or download. It's including both directions. Example: they may say the MPLS will transit 100Mb. They used a word like this because the circuit was actually 50Mb up and 50Mb down for example. Not meaning 100Mb was 100Mb up and 100Mb down. Do verify since they are not specific!